# Django. Get primary key of object after save form in database

Tags: django

I need to get pk of object after post and save form. Can help me, please?
View:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    new_ticket = form.save()
    address = form.cleaned_data['address'].encode('utf8')
    title = form.cleaned_data['title'].encode('utf8')
    recipient = form.cleaned_data['email'].encode('utf8')
    name = form.cleaned_data['name'].encode('utf8')
    room = form.cleaned_data['room'].encode('utf8')

    return super(CreateTicket, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `new_ticket` object has the `pk` since you already have saved it to the database by `form.save()`

So you just need to do:

```
new_ticket_id = new_ticket.pk
```

to get the id field of the object

Also, you do not need to read the form attributes again.

```
address = new_ticket.address.encode('utf8')
#.. and so on.
```